# persist JavaFX-ObservableList with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, javafx, eclipselink, derby

I'm trying to persist an ObservableList with JPA using the eclipselink API Version 2.6 with derby. JPA needs POJOs to persist. For JavaFX-Properties I can use this:

```
@Transient // avoid persisting
private StringProperty street = new SimpleStringProperty();

@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) //
public String getStreet() {
    return street.get();
}

public void setStreet(final String newStreet) {
    street.set(newStreet);
}
```

Works fine!
Well, the first guess is to use it in the same way for an ObservableList. My first try was to use a normal List:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Address> adrList;

public List<Address> getAdrList() {
    return adrList;
}

public void setAdrList(final List<Address> adrList) {
    this.adrList = adrList;
}
```

Works well! Let's change the List to an ObservableList. According to the StringProperty, I would use something like this:

```
private ObservableList<Address> adrList;

@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Address> getAdrList() {
    return adrList;
}

public void setAdrList(final List<Address> adrList) {
    this.adrList.setAll(adrList);
}
```

This works until the point I access the adrList. I get a NullPointerException cause the adrList is Null.
My Question is: How can I use my ObervableList with JPA? I thought I could cast the ObservableList to a List as long it's just an Implementation of List. But It seems not to work. Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The obvious fix would be to initialize `adrList` inline: `private ObservableList<Address> adrList = FXCollections.observableArrayList<>();`. Have you tried that? I would also recommend not trying to lazy initialize the data here (at least try to get it working with eager initialization first, as that is "easier" for the JPA implementation).

Comment: Given the nature of JPA collections, I think you want to use `this.adrList = FXCollections.observableList(adrList);` in your set-method, so changes to the List will be propagated into the original JPA-created collection.

Comment: Thank you James_D and VGR! Both of your fixes makes the code working well. :) The problem is that the list isn't loading lazy anymore. :/ Any idea why this happens now?

Comment: Check the logic in how a list gets added to your ObservableList.  Chances are the method building the observableList is touching the passed in list, causing it to be fetched.  You can test by making a mistake in your Address mappings so that when it gets fetched, it causes an exception that would show the stack trace, pointing out where exactly the lazy collection is getting fetched from.

Comment: You're presumably using an `ObservableList` because you're displaying the data in some JavaFX control. It's hard to even see a benefit to lazy loading in that case: you really don't want to go back to the database on the FX Application Thread anyway. So in any use case I can see for this, you should use eager loading. (Also think about how firing change events would work in conjunction with lazy loading: it would be very unpredictable.)